# Content view inside scroll view - why?

Tags: ios, xcode

I see that almost everyone use a dummy view inside *scroll view*, in the storyboard. Isn't *scroll view* a **view** by itself?

In this official [Apple docs link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1), it is stated that:

> For most common layout tasks, the logic becomes far easier if you use a dummy view or layout group to contain the scroll view’s content.

I did try using *scroll view* directly instead of having a *content view* (dummy view) as an intermediate, and found myself in constipated situations, and I don't know why.

Here are my questions:

1. Why and how does it become difficult to use *scroll view* directly?
2. What is, and how to use **layout group** as an alternative?
3. How to use *scroll view* directly, without having an intermediate dummy view?

Comment: What's the purpose of using `UIScrollView` if you don't have anything(view) to scroll in it? The scrollView needs the contentSize property which is not intrinsic.

Comment: @AmberK `UIScrollView` inherits `UIView`, right? That's one of the places where I got confused. It made me think, if a view can hold contents by itself, why can't scroll view?

Comment: you could put views directly in scrollview, there are no concrete rules for that, only recommendations. Every situation is different, use what suits best for you, best practices are not silver bullets.

Comment: @Taier, thank you, and it would be really helpful if you can suggest me some situation or use case to support the recommendations.

Comment: @RevanthKausikan, for example, you would like to show content on stack view inside scrollview. You dont need to make scrollview-dummuview-stackview-yourviews

Comment: @Taier, thanks! it makes sense.

Comment: @RevanthKausikan Who said it can't? It will if inner views satisfy the intrinsic size for scrollview just like normal view to define its frame. If you subview doesn't add a bottom constraint it will ambiguous content size which scroll view has but not view. If you want your subivew to be larger than scrollview then either it should be intrinsic or a specific height constraint should satisfy it. Eg: try adding a label with height constraint greater than your scroll view and then give bottom space to scrollview 0, it will calculate contentSize on its own.

Comment: @AmberK, Thank you for the explanation and the example. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frequently, elements are added dynamically. Many people find it easier to add them to a "content view" rather than adding them directly to the scroll view.

Personally, I find the direct method easier.

Without a dummy / content view, you simply constrain the elements to the scroll view itself, rather than to the content view.

Here are two examples. `ContentScrollViewController` and `DirectScrollViewController`. As you will see, they are almost identical. It's really a matter of preference... probably whichever method you *start* using will be the one you prefer. Note: For demonstration purposes, I often give elements starkly different background colors to make it easy to see layout frames.

Content View method:

```
class ContentScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.text = "Top Label"
        return v
    }()

    let bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.text = "Top Label"
        return v
    }()

    let contentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .orange
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(topLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(bottomLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain scrollView to all 4 sides with 20-pts padding
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // constrain contentView to all 4 sides of scrollView with 8-pts padding
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain topLabel 0-pts to top and leading of contentView
            topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            topLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel's top 800-pts from bottom of topLabel
            bottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 800.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel's leading 600-pts from trailing of topLabel
            bottomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 600.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel 0-pts to bottom and trailing of contentView
            bottomLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bottomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            ])

    }

}
```

Direct method:

```
class DirectScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.text = "Top Label"
        return v
    }()

    let bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.text = "Top Label"
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(topLabel)
        scrollView.addSubview(bottomLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain scrollView to all 4 sides with 20-pts padding
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // constrain topLabel 8-pts to top and leading of scrollView
            topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel's top 800-pts from bottom of topLabel
            bottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 800.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel's leading 600-pts from trailing of topLabel
            bottomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 600.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel 8-pts to bottom and trailing of scrollView
            bottomLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            bottomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            ])

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! The answer is detailed enough and aptly served the question. I am marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: And it would be really nice if you could also guide me with some information about **layout group**.

Comment: The phrase "layout group" appears only once on Apple's entire website, in the context of *"use a dummy view or layout group to contain the scroll view’s content"*. I believe it is simply using "dummy view" and "layout group" as two different, interchangeable terms to describe "grouping elements together." As far as I know, there is no such thing as a "layout group" (although, Unity3D appears to have Horizontal and Vertical Layout Group objects).

Answer (score 0):

See if you use content view inside scroll view you no need to programmatically calculate and set the content size of the scroll view in case of using Autolayout because your UI elements set autolayout constraints w.r.t to the content view and the content view will change its size as per the UI elements content. Scroll view having two different things one is its frame and another is its content size. So if not using content view layer u have to manually set the content size of the scroll view as per the UI elements content. Please check this : https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it! So the issue is the *content size*, and using a content view helps to define the frames, and we no need to manually set the size of every individual item nested in it.

Comment: If you have your constraints set correctly, you don't need to calculate and set `.contentSize` either way. See my answer...